# How can I get Grade 1 Lost Artifact Fragments?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I can't seem to get any Lost Artifact Fragments through my Archaeology missions.  I've been repeatedly doing the other missions that yield other Grade 1 materials in order to clear them out and hopefully have a mission that yields Grade 1 Artifact Fragments, with no luck.  Torhead claims ["Memoirs of a Crimelord"](http://www.torhead.com/crew-mission/1GW35by/memoirs-of-a-crimelord) gives them, but I've never seen that mission come up.

Is there something I'm missing here?  Any other way to get them (besides the GTN if someone sells some)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Artifact fragments can occasionally be received when harvesting color crystal nodes in the world, and can also be found as nodes themselves (I've seen them in/around the Dark Temple on Dromund Kaas).

If the mission isn't showing up, *and* you meet the requirements for it (35 skill - I've sent Khem on this mission myself, so I know it exists), well, you're out of luck, because there are more missions than there are slots for them, so a random batch gets picked, and *Memoirs* wasn't among them.

In that case, you'll want to reset your available missions: log out / in, change zone, or complete any other mission.

Comment: I maxed out my skill a few days ago and spent hours doing the other missions trying to get one with these :P I'll probably go to the Jedi Temple and harvest things until I get some.  Thanks.

Comment: You also get them from reverse engineering Grade 1 items you've crafted.

Comment: Ha, so the first time I log in today the mission is there, and I got it four times in a row.  Awesome.  Also got one or two in some igneous crystal formations, though it seems I can only find Sacred Artifact nodes and not other types of artifacts.  Anyways, thanks again.

Comment: @MatthewRead igneous is the rank 2 color crystal node, which is why you're getting the rank 2 artifacts. If you find amorphous crystal nodes, you'll probably get the former.

Comment: Actually I got some rank 1 artifacts in the rank 2 color crystal nodes.  I was saying that all the artifact nodes I found today were rank 2 and not rank 1, sorry for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 1):

On Coruscant in the Black Sun Territory there are lost artifact fragments mixed in with color crystals all over the place. Rubat crystals are also abundant!

Answer (score 0):

With the crew skill Archaeology you will be able to find these around the world. Another quick way is to buy them off of the Galactic Trade Network from, for example, your factions Fleet or from the GTN stations in Kaas City's trade quarters.

I don't think I ever found them =in= crystal nodes, but I found plenty plenty outside in the world. I have my graphics setting maxed out and I found it a bit hard to see the artifacts on the ground, you see the markers on the minimap though and can easily snoop around in the area where its supposed to be.

Comment: Also they have now a blue writing overlay hovering above to find them better.

Answer (score 0):

If you are desperate for lost artifact fragments, please take a look in your stronghold.  The stronghold accessories you got when you first moved in will include a crystal arrangement.

Click on it for rubat and lost artifact fragments.  You can get 5 of each every time you harvest it, and if it has rested it yields two harvests per hour or something like that.

Also your "trash can" or that messy pile of canned grunge yields cybertech goodies.  The plant with the tiny pinkish flowers, that looks kind of weedy is a biochem plant, and last but not least... your safe yields money boxes in case you need coin to craft things :D!  I discovered this by accident, and I hope it helps you a little bit!

Comment: This is a good addition, I have made a lot of use of my Stronghold gathering decorations.

Answer (score -2):

if the mission isn't showing up, do all grade 1 missions available to you, after that it shows up one time. rinse and repeat.
Or alternatively 'The Works' section in Coruscant is full with Artifact Fragment Nodes.

Comment: I noted in my question that I was running through the missions.